# How to serialize protobuf message with schema id

Tags: php, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, confluent-schema-registry

Looking for a library or algorithm that implements serialization of a message in protobuf format with schema version which retrieved from confluent schema registry. I use the php-rdkafka extension to send messages to Kafka topic.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for libraries are off-topic. Please see [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the messages is [documented here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format)

For protobuf - it is a byte array of

```
magic-byte, schema-id, message-indexes, protobuf-payload
```

You can find source code [here](https://github.com/flix-tech/avro-serde-php/blob/master/src/Protocol.php) / [here](https://github.com/flix-tech/avro-serde-php/blob/master/src/Objects/RecordSerializer.php) that generates the same wire-format for Avro using the Confluent Registry, and you'd need to do something very similar once you have raw bytearray for any protobuf object.

And that library is what is used by [php-rdkafka-examples](https://github.com/php-kafka/php-kafka-examples/blob/main/src/ext-php-rdkafka/php-kafka-lib/avroProducer.php) repo